# Hibernate 4.3.4 StandardServiceRegistryBuilder

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt

I'm getting an error when creating a serviceRegistry. I'm using Hibernate 4.3.4 with GWT and a  mySQL DB. The hibernate jar is included and I don't get any errors in the code but when I'm running it I get:

```
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.Long com.coma.comaexjobb.client.UserService.saveUser(com.coma.comaexjobb.shared.Users)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry
```

My **HibernateUtil.java**

```
package com.coma.comaexjobb.Util;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;
    }
 }
```

Anyone knows what to do? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like the problem is  in `import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;`,
maybe the **jar is missing** in WEB-INF (note that GWT most of the time needs both: Jars and the source code) in your project then the GWT cannot find the class: `org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry`.

Comment: Thank you! The .jar was only included under referenced libraries and was not included in WEB-INF lib.

Comment: which file? would nice to know how exactly you fixed our own problem? 6077